# Is this training dataset enough for training and testing classification model?

Tags: machine-learning, weka, svm, training-data, sample-size

My training dataset contains just 2 classes with 40 features.

In case 1, class 1 has 35 samples and class 2 has 700 samples.

In case 2, class 1 has 65 samples and class 2 has the same value as above.

Is my training dataset enough for constructing the model using SVM classifier or some other classifiers?

I'm using WEKA. Testing options are **10-fold cross-validation** and **%66** and i get very good results.

Answer (score 0):

You satisfied by result, so it means that you have enough data. It's hard to tell how much data you need, it depends on which problem you are solving exactly, how much noise in data you have, what features, etc.

I described it here in second part: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31567143/1030820